# Paper.js простые фигуры

Tags: javascript

При попытке нарисовать прямоугольник выдает ошибку

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var CANVAS = document.getElementById('canvas-view');
    paper.install(CANVAS);
    var rectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(10, 10), new Point(200, 200));
    var path = new Path.Rectangle(rectangle);
    path.fillColor = '#e9e9ff';
});
```

А именно в файле **paper-full.min.js**, а ноги растут из *var path = new Path.Rectangle(rectangle);*

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentStyle' of null
```

Страница на которой рисую

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bubble Sort</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <!-- Kube Framework -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/kube.min.css" />
    <!-- My CSS file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />

    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="view">
        <canvas id="canvas-view"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script src="js/kube.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/paper-core.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/paper-full.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/form-actions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bubble-sort.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#sorting-options').actions();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Пример на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8xy4zvh1/)

Comment: При виде вопросов такого типа, у меня появляется желание увидеть работающий (или не работающий) пример на http://jsfiddle.net/ , где это все можно было бы пощупать сразу.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8xy4zvh1/ линия рисуется, а прямоугольник нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас нет объекта Rectangle в глобальной видимости. Все инкапсулировано в объекте paper. http://jsfiddle.net/8xy4zvh1/1/

Примеры в документации http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/using-javascript-directly/

```
var path = new paper.Path.Rectangle(new paper.Point(10, 10), new paper.Point(200, 200));
path.fillColor = '#e9e9ff';
```

Comment: Ага, http://jsfiddle.net/8xy4zvh1/2/

Comment: спасибо, проблема была в этом и кое-что еще)